# Hibernate mapping problem

Tags: java, hibernate

I have some objects mapped via hibernate.

A has one B

B has many C

I create B, give it a list of Cs, and set the B in A.  Save it and everything goes to the right place in the db.

When I retrieve the B, I can call b.getCs() and the Cs are there.  Cool.

My problem is, when I retrieve the A, the B is there, but when I call a.b.getCs() I get the following error:

> org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException
>   - could not initialize proxy - no Session - 10890

Does anyone know why this is not working?

Comment: The lazy-loading problem is a very common one in Hibernate. Stackoverflow is full of questions and answers about this, I suggest using the search field up there .../

Comment: You should check your FetchType

Comment: If you provide more information it may be useful. How and where are you using getCs() and getB()? FetchType? What kind of operation are you doing? etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable lazy-loading on you mappping, if you are using xml for your mapping, try this

```
<hibernate-mapping default-lazy="false">
```

But when using this you need to consider your performance issue, as this will make your program really slow on a big query result.

if using Annotation:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
public List<A> getAllA(){
   //this is your method to get all A's list
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your mapping to disable lazy-load of C on Bs.  Of course, if you then try to retrieve a large number of Bs at the same time, you'll suffer a performance hit.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention the type of application.  If it's a web application, consider using Open Session in View (https://community.jboss.org/wiki/OpenSessionInView).  That may also help.